# Driver used by MySQL Workbench to Connect to MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am seeing different behaviour of an sql statement when run from DBeaver which uses jdbc driver than the one from MySQL workbench.

Example

```
mysql> create table test (processing_ts timestamp null);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)
```

in Dbeaver below statement gives error because the time is below the range of timestamp datatype

```
insert into test values ('1970-01-01 00:00:00');
```

In MySQL Workbench, runs fine without error however the value inserted is null.

```
insert into test values ('1970-01-01 00:00:00');
```

So wanted to know what is the driver that MySQL workbench uses for connecting to MySQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench uses the [MySQL C++ connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/).